# recv() fails to read last chunk

Tags: c++, unix-socket

The function below reads incoming data perfectly but only if the **last** data chunk  is **smaller** than `BUFFSIZE`. If the size of the last `buff` happens to be equal to `BUFFSIZE`, then the program tries to `recv` again in the next loop iteration and sets `bytes` to 1844674407379551615 (most probably integer overflow) and repeats this in an infinite loop... Why? Why isn't it 0? And why doesn't it escape the loop at this stage?

```
std::string getMsg (int clientFileDescriptor, int timeout_sec)
{
    std::string msg;
    msg.reserve(BUFFSIZE * 10);

    char buff[BUFFSIZE + 1];

    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    //set a timeout for reading and writing
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = timeout_sec;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt (clientFileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof(tv));


    while (true)
    {
        size_t bytes = recv (clientFileDescriptor, buff, BUFFSIZE, 0);

        std::cout << "bytes read: " << bytes << std::endl;

        if (0 < bytes && bytes <= BUFFSIZE)
        {
            msg.append(buff, bytes);

            //'buff' isn't full  so this was the last chunk of data 
            if (bytes < BUFFSIZE)
                break;
        }
        else if (!bytes) //EOF or socket shutdown by the client
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EINTR) 
                continue;
            
            //We cannot continue due to other erros (e.g. EBADF/socket not available)
            break;
        }
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: And since `recv` returns up to `BUFFSIZE`, you can't count on `if (bytes < BUFFSIZE)` really being the end of the message.

Comment: Are you sure `size_t` is signed on your platform?

Comment: Probably need `ssize_t`rather than `size_t`.

Comment: If you turn the warning level up on your compiler it may tell you some of these mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `size_t` is unsigned on your platform. So if the `recv` times out, `recv` returns -1 and `bytes` overflows. Your code doesn't correctly handle this case due to the overflow.

This is just wrong:

```
        //'buff' isn't full  so this was the last chunk of data
```

It's entirely possible `buff` wasn't full because the last chunk of data hadn't been received yet. Tou should actually add code to detect the end of a message rather than relying on a timeout to find it for you if your application protocol supports messages of different sizes.

Unfortunately, you haven't given us the code for the other end of the connection nor specified how your application protocol works, so I have no idea what the other side does or expects. So it's not possible to give you more useful suggestions.

Comment: `size_t` is always unsigned and `ssize_t` is always signed.

Comment: You mean I should add something like a trailing character and search every chunk for its occurence?

Comment: @ScepticalJule That would be one way to do it and that might make sense for your protocol. Text protocols somestimes use lind endings that way. String protocols sometimes use nul bytes that way. It may make more sense to precede the message with a fixed number of bytes that encode the length of the message. It may make sense to tokenize the message into chunks with each chunk encoding its size somehow (as HTTP's chunked encoding does). You might decide to mark the end of a message by closing the connection as early HTTP did.

Comment: @ScepticalJule a trailing character *may* work for textual data, but it won't work for binary data, since you won't know if the data contains the character you want to use for the delimiter. But everything else David mentioned are viable solutions.

Answer (score 3):

> If the size of the last `buff` happens to be equal to `BUFFSIZE`, then the program tries to `recv` again in the next loop iteration and sets `bytes` to 1844674407379551615 (most probably integer overflow) and repeats this in an infinite loop... Why?

Because there is no more data to read from the socket, and you are using a read timeout, so `recv()` fails and returns `-1` (and `errno` will be `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`).  `recv()` returns a *signed* `ssize_t`, not an *unsigned* `size_t` as you are using.  `size_t` can't hold a negative value, so if you assign a *signed* `-1` to a `size_t`, it will wrap to the largest positive value that `size_t` can hold.

> Why isn't it 0?

Because it can't be.  `recv()` does not return 0 on timeout, only on graceful disconnect.

> And why doesn't it escape the loop at this stage?

Because `recv()` is returning `-1`.  Thus, `if (0 < bytes && bytes <= BUFFSIZE)` and `if (!bytes)` are both false, so your logic falls into your final `else` block, which is checking `errno` and then `continue`'ing the loop on an `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` error (what is the point of setting a read timeout if you are just going to ignore it?).  And then `recv()` times out and returns `-1` again, and your logic `continue`'s the loop again, over and over, forever.

TCP has no concept of message boundaries, so you have to handle this manually in your code. There are several different ways you can solve this issue:

1. Set a *reasonable* timeout, and then break the loop (and close the connection) if the timeout elapses.  This is not advisable for detecting the end of a complete message, since you don't know whether the timeout elapsed because end-of-data was reached or if a network failure/hiccup occurred.  Also, if the sender happens to send a new message within the timeout, you will treat it as a continuation of the previous message.  So, you need a more *explicit* way of determining the true completion of each message, and fail accordingly on actual errors.
2. In which case, you can send the data's full size *before* sending the actual data, if you know the size up front. Then, regardless of how you read the chunks, simply stop the reading loop once you have received the specified number of bytes.  Do not read more than you are told to read.
3. Otherwise, you can prefix each chunk with a header that specifies how many data bytes are in the chunk.  After you are finished sending all of the data, send a final chunk with a data size of 0. Stop the reading loop when you receive a chunk with a data size of 0.
4. Otherwise, just *gracefully* close the socket connection after sending all of the data.  Stop the reading loop when `recv()` returns `<= 0`, and process the message only if `recv()` had returned `0`, and handle errors if `recv()` has returned `-1` instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question - it's really helpful. I just don't understand why there are so many implementations in the internet, but not a single correct one taking all of these aspects into account.

Comment: @ScepticalJule um, *every* viable implementation takes these aspects into account. It is just something that every TCP user has to deal with to ensure the stability of their connections.